# I want to prevent the user from entering negative values when prompted for an entry. How do I go about this in this code?

Tags: c++

How do I prevent the following C++ code from taking in negative values? Any zero, positive integer, or positive decimal I enter as a user produces correct results, but when I enter a negative value I want the program to tell the user that what they've entered is not a positive integer or decimal, and to re-attempt their entry.

**main driver file:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include "convert.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   string str;
   cout <<
       "Please enter a string representing a positive integer or decimal: ";
   cin >> str;
   convertToNumeric ctn(str);
   long int integerValue = ctn.getIntValue();
   double doubleValue = ctn.getDecValue();
   double integral;

   /* If the string represents an integer value, adding decimal portion to
    * the decimal value.
    */
   if (std::modf(doubleValue, &integral) == 0)
   {
       cout << "Integer Conversion: " << integerValue << endl;
       cout << "Decimal Conversion: " << std::fixed << std::setprecision(1)
           << integral <<endl;
   }
   /*
    * Else, display the values normally.
    */
   else
   {
       cout << "Integer Conversion: " << integerValue << endl;
       cout << "Decimal Conversion: " << doubleValue << endl;
   }
   /*
    * Demonstrating that the converted values are useable with
    * long int-specific and double-specific operations.
    */
   cout << endl;
   cout << "Demonstration of long int: " << integerValue << " + 100 = " <<
       (integerValue + 100) << endl;
   cout << "Demonstration of decimal: " << doubleValue << " + 100.12 = " <<
       (doubleValue + 100.12) << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

**convert.cpp file:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "convert.h"

using namespace std;

convertToNumeric::convertToNumeric()
{
   str = "123";
}

/*
* This accessor function is the overloaded constructor that takes a string
* and calls the convert method to convert into respective integer and
* decimal value. There is not return value. The input is s, which is the
* string to be converted.
*/
convertToNumeric::convertToNumeric(string s)
{
   str = s;
   if(convert(str))
   {
       cout << "Conversion Successful!" << endl;
   }
   else
   {
       cout << "Conversion failed." <<endl;
   }
}

/*
* This mutator function serves the purpose of converting a string into its
* respective integer and decimal values. The input is s, which is the
* string to be converted. The function returns a boolean value indicating
* whether conversion is successful or not.
*/
bool convertToNumeric::convert(string s)
{
   bool success = false;
   bool dotFound = false;

   /*
    * Here, we are looping through each character in the string and storing
    * the integer portion in cstk1 and the decimal portion in cstk2.
    * Ex: If s = 123.45, cstk1 = 321 and cstk2 = 54
    * (since the stack follows LIFO)
    */
   for(unsigned int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++)
   {
       if(s[i] == '.') dotFound = true;
       else if(dotFound)
       {
           cstk2.push(s[i]);
       }
       else
       {
       cstk1.push(s[i]);
       }
   }

   /*
    * Here, we are popping out each value from stack cstk1 and generating
    * the integer value.
    * Ex: s = 123.45 and cstk1 = 321, num = 0
    * Iteration 1: num = 0 + (3 * 1) = 3
    * Iteration 2: num = 3 + (2 * 10) = 23
    * Iteration 3: num = 23 + (1 * 100) = 123
    * Now intValue = 123
    */
   long int num = 0; int multiplyValue = 1;
   char val = '0';
   while(cstk1.pop(val))
   {
       int valInInt = val - '0';
       num += (valInInt * multiplyValue);
       multiplyValue *= 10;
   }
   intValue = num;

   /*
    * Here, we are popping out each value from stack cstk2 and generating
    * the decimal value.
    * Ex: s = 123.45 and cstk2 = 54, num = 0, doubleValue = 123
    * (equated to integer value)
    * Iteration 1: num = 0 + (5 * 1) = 5
    * Iteration 2: num = 5 + (4 * 10) = 45
    * Iteration 3: num = 45 / 100 = 0.45
    * Now doubleValue = 123 + 0.45 = 123.45
    */
   doubleValue = double(num);
   num = 0; multiplyValue = 1;
   while(cstk2.pop(val))
   {
       int valInInt = val - '0';
       num += (valInInt * multiplyValue);
       multiplyValue *= 10;
   }
   doubleValue += (double(num) / multiplyValue);
   success = true;
   return success;
}

/*
* The accessor function below is returning the integer value of the string
* that has been converted.
*/
long int convertToNumeric::getIntValue()
{
   return intValue;
}

/*
* The accessor function below is returning the double value of the string
* that has been converted.
*/
double convertToNumeric::getDecValue()
{
   return doubleValue;
}
```

Reproducible examples:

Correct:
[Positive number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x401X.png)

Incorrect:
[Negative number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1iMA4.png)
[Letter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOmjB.png)

Comment: This is a lot of code, is all of it necessary for the question? can you narrow it down?

Comment: Do you need to account for non-numerical inputs? Or just negatives? If the latter, it's as simple as a loop with an if check.

Comment: imho comments that say "This is an accessor function." are really bad. Comments should assist code when code alone is not sufficient to express its intend. Comments that just repeat what the code already says are redundant and of no use. Just my very personal opinion. In any case they take lots of space in your code and they arent needed for a [mcve] (same goes for all the blank lines)

Comment: Unfortunately, those kind of comments don't get killed by the teacher/grader a lot of the time.

Comment: Concerning [mcve]: you could make an 4-5 lines example that reads input from user. In your current code I couldnt even spot where you read input and validate it on first sight

Comment: Both actually! Good catch. @sweenish

Comment: 95% of the shown code that has nothing to do with input validation must be removed, before this question gets closed as off-topic.

Comment: I have now added examples. @idclev463035818

Comment: I think you misunderstood. "minimal" stands for "remove everything not relevant for the question from the code". What has popping and pushing to do with taking user input?

Comment: I have now removed everything that is irrelevant to question. @idclev463035818

Comment: I have now done so. @SamVarshavchik

Comment: I have narrowed it down. @Borgleader

Comment: Minimal: only the code required to demonstrate the problem with as little user interaction as possible. Reproducible: The code must either compile and demonstrate the error or not compile and produce the one error or warning you are asking about. It's not always easy to make a MRE. We ask for them because MRE is a distillation of very powerful programming techniques. More often than not producing a MRE shows you what you have wrong and how to fix it without asking the question.

Comment: @CamNewton Make a small program from scratch. You only want to check that the string doesn't contain the representation of a negative number, right? It shouldn't take more than a few lines to demonstrate the problem. Also, why do you put so many blank lines in the code? It makes it necessary to scroll line crazy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quick way to do it:

```cpp
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

bool has_decimal(const std::string& str)
{
    return !(std::string::npos == str.find_first_of('.'));
}

bool conversion_was_complete(std::size_t length, std::size_t converted)
{
    return length == converted;
}

int main()
{
    std::string input;
    bool valid = false;
    union Number {
        double d;
        std::uint64_t i;
    } number;

    bool isInt = false;

    do {
        std::cout << "Enter a positive number: ";
        std::getline(std::cin, input);

        // Catch negative numbers here
        if (input[0] == '-') {
            std::cerr << "Invalid number entered.\n";
            continue;
        }

        std::size_t location;
        if (has_decimal(input)) {
            try {
                number.d = std::stod(input, &location);
            } catch (std::invalid_argument& e) {
                // do nothing, it's handled elsewhere
            }
        } else {
            isInt = true;
            try {
                number.i = std::stoi(input, &location);
            } catch (std::invalid_argument& e) {
                // do nothing, it's handled elsewhere
            }
        }

        if (conversion_was_complete(input.length(), location)) {
            valid = true;
        } else {
            std::cerr << "Invalid number entered.\n";
            isInt = false; // Entering words will set this to true, so it needs
                // to be reset
        }
    } while (!valid);

    std::cout << "You entered " << (isInt ? number.i : number.d) << ".\n";
}
```

The whole input thing will probably end up in a function for your use-case. My functions could just be lambdas in that function if you don't want the helpers floating around.

The `try`/`catch` blocks are needed because `std::stoi` and `std::stod` will throw if they cannot do any conversion; it handles the the scenario where the first character is not numeric or a `'-'`. I chose a `union` because it seemed like the the best way to store your value to me. The one issue is the flag indicating the actual type for printing purposes. You'll probably just want to wrap it all up in a class to clean it up. Another option is to just use a `double`. That depends on your requirements.

Comment: I've actually never used the cstdint library. What's it for?

Comment: It gets you different `int` types where you can know the size explicitly. In the union, I declare an unsigned 64 bit integer. I wanted the two members to be the same size.